# Div inside col not getting css properties applied?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone explain me why the div map is not getting it's css applied when it's inside a col? Just started on bootstrap and couldn't find anything from searches

```
   <style>
        #map {
            width: 25%;
            height: 25%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <container-fluid>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="map">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">10</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">15</div>
        </div>
    </container-fluid>

</body>
```

Comment: try to give the width and height in px. Also, I believe the <container-fluid> should be  <div class="container-fluid">

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a percentage for height, unless the parent has a defined height.

The 25% width is fine, but you'll have to provide a fixed height - change it to `200px` and you'll see the blue area:

https://jsfiddle.net/97347rnn/

edit: I also had to change the column defs to `xs` instead of `md` to show in the small jsfiddle window, you don't have to do that. I had to change `<container-fluid>` to `<div class="container-fluid">` to make it work.

Comment: Is it possible to set the col height then? I need the div map to be 100% height :l @Starscream1984

Comment: You can set everything in the hierarchy to 100% height, starting with HTML, then your final 100% on the `#map` div will take effect: https://jsfiddle.net/xycq2u6h/